# Grid layout with css?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create some kind of grid layout with css:

Having a content div, which is devided into 2 colums: main + right.

Now I have 2 kinds of elements. I always want these elements to align side by side.

So I'm having something like this:

```
#outerPanel{
 width:100%; 
 float:right; 
 position:relative; 
  }

#rightcol{
 width:35%; 
 float:right; 
 position:relative; 
 }

#maincol{
 float: left; 
 position: relative; 
 width:65%; 
 }
```

and my index.xhtml:

```
    <p:panel id="outerPanel">

            <h:panelGroup id="maincol">
                <ui:include src="table1.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup id="rightcol">
                <ui:include src="input1.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:panelGroup id="maincol">
                <ui:include src="table2.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup id="rightcol">
                <ui:include src="input2.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>


    </p:panel>
```

Of course this does only work for the first occurrence of the id's, as one is not allowed to reuse the id.
But this shows what I'm trying to do. How can I else set it up?

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Of course this does only work for the first occurrence of the id's, as one is not allowed to reuse the id.*

Just use `class` instead of `id`.

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="maincol">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup styleClass="rightcol">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup styleClass="maincol">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup styleClass="rightcol">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

with

```css
.rightcol {
    ... 
}

.maincol {
    ...
}
```

Comment: niiiice! tyvm did not know about class!

Answer (score 0):

I normally just use panelGrids to do that sort of thing. I create classes for each column and use them in the columClasses attributes. I find it a little easier than making sure my CSS and the theme's CSS play nice together. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

i think it's better that you enclose each mainCol and rightCol in another div or other element that contains each panel group like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="maincol">
        <ui:include src="table1.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="rightcol">
        <ui:include src="input1.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</div>
```

and by the way, It's not a good practice to use id of the elements if it's used more than once it won't display as you want it. You might want to use class="mainCol" or styleClass in your case.

in your css:

```
#outerPanel{
    width:100%; 
    float:right;
    margin: auto; /*if you want to center out the content*/
    /*position:relative;*/ /*what do you want to use relative for?*/
}

.col {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.rightcol{
    width:35%; 
    float:right; 
    /*position:relative;*/
}

.maincol{
    float: left; 
    /*position: relative;*/
    width:65%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a CSS class: 
when working with the float attribute on DIV's, I always use a div with the attribute "clear: both" after the outlining div's.

For example:

**CSS**

```
.container { width: 100% }
.left { width: 49%; float: left }
.right { width: 49%; float: left }
.clear { clear: both }
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>DIVS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">Some Content</div>
        <div class="right">Some Content</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this puts you in the right direction to solve your issue.