# CSS float pushdown

Tags: css, css-float

I've looked through other posts regarding CSS floats, but have not yet found an answer.

I have several div with same width (1/3 of screen). They are all set to float left. When one is longer than the others, it pushes the following blocks down.

I've made an example which you can see at http://apsam.dk/misc/float-pushdown-problem/index.php (the yellow div is pushed down by the blue div).

If I missed the answer in a post, please point me to it. I've looked throug alot.

EDIT to clarify. The question is: How to avoid that the yellow div gets pushed down.

Answer (score 4):

To start a new line, please enter a div with the `clear: both;` attribute.

See my answer on another post here, which shows an example:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350084/grid-layout-with-css/9350238#9350238)

Comment: I didn't edit anything just emphasizes `clear:both;` by surrounding it with '``', click on the edit time to see the changes and you can from ther rollback my changes, sorry :(

Comment: No problem MGA, it's better this way... Thanks for the addition... :)

Comment: Does not solve the problem. The problem is that the divs are pushed down, which is only made worse by adding clear.

Answer (score 0):

Floats don't "jigsaw puzzle" together like that. Each of your floats has a height, that height is seen and honored. You can't get `.yellow` to ignore the height of `.blue`, especially in the same container. You could use positioning to move `.yellow` up.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/YZLjs/)

Or, you could use another div and treat it as your left column and have it contain the green and yellow divs.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/YZLjs/1/)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I think I will choose your second method since I don't control how many divs will be in each column.